# OpenId Connect Permission/Authorization in Claims Flow

Tags: oauth, openid, jwt, openid-connect, identityserver4

We are implementing IdentityServer4 with MS.Identity for SSO, Authentication & Authorization using the Implicit Flow for our handful of SPAs and WebAPIs(we own all).

With Implicit Flow the Id_Token is where we place extra 'claims.'  [Spec here.](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken)

The access_token does not contain custom permission claims as per [this.](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/678#issuecomment-272206783)

The [Implicit Flow Spec is here.](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitFlowAuth)

Question:  **What is the flow of granting and removing permissions?**

- How does the client know Permissions/Claims have changed without polling the User Info Endpoint?
- How does the resource server know?

Revocation of Id_token is not spec.  It seems the utility of claims in tokens knowing the permissions no longer applies with my understanding of OpenID Conenct.

Am I missing an obvious built in spec'd solution or do we implement some kind of re-issuance of Id_Token when when permissions have changed?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens don't contain permissions. They contain identity data about the client & user.

https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I read this article and shared it with my co-worker a couple weeks ago when we decided to implement refresh tokens, ultimately leading to a rewrite of our entire Authentication/Authorization. Ultimately the article closes with 'Stay Tuned.'  Is there an existing solution or pattern anywhere or correlated to OpenId Connect?

Comment: To address payload size, we are encoding Enums as Shorts to 2 Bytes ea, and then Base64URL encoding it.

Answer (score 0):

In light of Dominick's Answer.

I am going implement a Permission/Authorization Server and end point.

SPA and WebAPI clients can call it for permissions with Authentication.  Now we can return any custom Permission Object we need.

In the access_token we will add a custom 'Permission ETAG' such that if a User's permissions change, each client knows to fetch the new permissions.

Constructive criticism welcome..